# Downloading a file from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blob

I am running into an issue trying to download a CSV file from Google Cloud Storage. For some reason, it keeps downloading the file as bytes instead of readable text. When I open the downloaded CSV in Excel, Excel is somehow smart enough to convert it to readable text. What am I missing here?
I've checked Google's docs and I can't find any good information how to accomplish them. Thank you in advance!

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket_name")
blob = bucket.blob("csv_file.csv")
blob = blob.download_as_string()
blob = blob.decode('utf-8')
blob = io.StringIO(blob)  # tranform bytes to string here
print(blob)
```

This is the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Which version of Python? What is your definition of "readable text"? Python typically stores string data as UTF8. What is the format of the orginal CSV file? The method `download_as_string()` is deprecated. Use `download_as_bytes()`. Then you have a Python byte object. To display (print) that object convert it to a string using `blob.decode()`. I do not know why you are using `io.StringIO(blob)`. That function is for streams. The format of data is determined when you create and store it and you can only convert it after reading.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am using version 3.7.8. Readable text for me is UTF-8. I made the suggested changes and I am still getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte`. There is a possibility that the file was saved strangely, but somehow Excel can open it.

Comment: I would need to see the first 8 - 16 bytes of the raw file (object) to guess the format. There are many formats for encoding string data. UTF8 is just one of many. There is also the possibility that the file is binary and is not encoded. You mention that Excel can open it which means you saved the data to a file. Can you open the file in an editor? Some editors will tell you the file format.

Comment: One additional item. To display string data on your screen/terminal/session, the system's locale is important. There are a lot of details that you need to figure out to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: @JohnHanley I can open it in an editor and see that the first 16 bytes are `504b 0304 1400 0`. Google doesn't seem to specify what the format is.

Comment: Google does not determine the format. That is why data in Cloud Storage is called "blobs". The program that wrote the data determines the format. You state the editor shows the first 16 bytes as XXX. What is the editor? What mode is it displaying in? The devil is in the details. Start investigating.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think you're on to something here! I just learned that the creator of the file was actually saving it as an _Excel document_ and _manually_ changing the file extension from .xlsx to .csv. That's likely the issue. Thank you so much, John.

Comment: Now your problem and the details are making sense. The format of .xlsx is very different than .csv. In those 16 bytes you showed, strings do not have binary zeros in the middle unless they are arrays of strings. A binary format such as xlsx can.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the code from the official documentation, with the function `blob.download_to_filename ()`. Why are you using `blob.download_as_string()` ?

[Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python)

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```